# Can't see why this is segfaulting

Tags: c++, nodes

```
class Node {
private:
    Node *left = NULL, *right = NULL;
    char data;
public:
    Node(char new_data) {
        data = new_data;
    }
    Node *get_left() {
        return left;
    }
    Node *get_right() {
        return right;
    }
    char get_data() {
        return data;
    }
    void set_data(char new_data) {
        data = new_data;
    }
};
```

I've debugged it (using gdb as well as cout) and it seems that the set_data function is the problem. Why?

There's a lot more code, but I'm assuming more code isn't necessary.

EDIT:

```
class tree {
private:
    Node *root;
public:
    tree(char ch) {
        cout << "ASDASD"; //using this to identify error
        root->set_data(ch);
        cout << root->get_data(); //using this to identify error
    }
};
```

EDIT 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tree.h"
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main () {
char c;

cout << "Enter a series of letters: ";

cin >> c;
tree t(c); //sets first one to root
while(cin) { //change??
    cin >> c;
    if (isdigit(c)) break;
    Node *n;
    n->set_data(c);
    t.insert(n);
}
}
```

Code is supposed to read from the keyboard until reading a number. It reads all of the letters, but when I type a number to try to exit, it segfaults.

Comment: Watch for `NULL` nodes as you're walking the tree.

Comment: I'm not sure that I am doing anything with null nodes. The tree class has a constructor that uses set_data() to set its root node. I've updated the original post to include the main part of the tree class. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: When does `root` get set to an instance of a `Node*`?

Comment: Well, your root node isn't allocated (`root` points to nothing).  Something like `root = new Node( ch );` in your tree constructor would probably help.

Comment: Shit. Okay, I got it, thanks. I had a feeling this was the problem but I couldn't see it.

Comment: Hey, could you check the code again? It includes my main.cc. I fixed the old error, but here's a new error. It segfaults after reading everything for some reason. I can't understand what gdb is trying to tell me.

Comment: You've made the exact same mistake again. `Node *n;` just declares a pointer, but it isn't set to point to anything. I suggest you encapsulate all node creation inside `tree`.

Comment: YOu have to allocate all nodes. `Node *n = new Node(c);`

Comment: Wow, alright thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
class tree {
private:
    Node *root;
public:
    tree(char ch) {
        cout << "ASDASD"; //using this to identify error
        root->set_data(ch); // **HERE**
        cout << root->get_data(); //using this to identify error
    }
};
```

At that point, `root` doesn't point to anything. So trying to dereference it is an error. Before you can use the thing a pointer points to, you have to make the pointer point to something.

And you have the same problem here:

```
Node *n;
n->set_data(c);
```

The `set_data` function is used to set a `Node`'s data. So you must already have a `Node` to call it. Nowhere do you create a `Node`, and `n` doesn't point to one here.